# Two spinners, spinner2 depends on spinner1

Tags: android

I have two spinners when i select spinner1 it displays categories example jobs,real-estate etc.. and spinner2 contains sub-categories which is related to specific categories in spinner1 for example If user select jobs in spinner1 then spinner2 should display only jobs sub-categories like hot jobs, software, hardware etc If in spinner1 real-estate then in spinner two it should display rental, lease etc. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Check [This tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-spinner-tutorial.html)

Comment: Mark the answer that really helped you in solving your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple terms, you have to register for ItemSelectedListener for Spinner 1 and based on selected value, set adapter of Spinner2

Code snippet :

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                if(position==1)
                  adapterForSpinner2=new ArrayAdapter..... //Depends on your data
                else if(position==2)
                   adapterForSpinner2=new ArrayAdapter.....//Depends on your data

                //Setting up adapter based on selection  
                spinner2.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner2);        
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
```

Comment: spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2); getting error Cannot cast from View to Spinner

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ddServerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    ddServerPath.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

}

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item selected local "+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //sincronizare dropdouwn list
    if (view == ddServerName.getSelectedView()) ddServerPath.setSelection(i);
    else ddServerName.setSelection(i);
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained your solution. Just posting code is not as helpful as you think.